# Unable to call function inside render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a function from inside render() menthod. But its saying method does not exist

Following is my constructor method

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={tournaments:[
      {
        "img":"http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg",
        "tn":"8th Shuttlers Corporate Badminton Tournament 2018",
        "dt":"20 jan 2018",
        "sp":"599",
        "ven":"oyeplay sports private limited, HSR layout",
        "venlink":"www.yahoo.com",
        "tl":"http://localhost/oyetournament/8th-Shuttlers-Corporate-Badminton-Tournament-2018"
      },
      {
        "img":"http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg",
        "tn":"9th Shuttlers Corporate Badminton Tournament 2018",
        "dt":"20 feb 2018",
        "sp":"699",
        "ven":"oyeplay sports private limited, HSR layout",
        "venlink":"www.google.com",
        "tl":"http://localhost/oyetournament/8th-Shuttlers-Corporate-Badminton-Tournament-2019"
      }
    ]}
    this.getSlide=this.getSlide.bind(this);
  }

getSlide(tournament){
    return <div class="item active">
      <div className={cssstyles.hero}>
           <MediaQuery query="(min-device-width: 600px)">
              <h1 >{tournament.tn}</h1>
              <i class="fa fa-calendar legend" id="date" style={styles.date_icon}></i><span class="legend" style={styles.date}>{tournament.dt}</span>
              <div style={styles.div}><i id="addr" class="fa fa-map-marker legend" style={styles.addr_icon}></i><a class="legend"  href={tournament.venlink} style={styles.addr}>{tournament.ven}</a></div>
              <div>
                <span class="legend" style={styles.startfrom}>Starts from</span> <i style={styles.rupee_icon} class="fa legend">&#xf156;</i><span style={styles.rupee} class="legend">{tournament.sp}/-</span>
                <a href={tournament.tl} class="legend" style={styles.booknow}>Book Now</a>
              </div>
            </MediaQuery>

            <MediaQuery query="(max-device-width: 600px)">
              <h1>{tournament.tn}</h1>
              <div style={styles.div}><i class="fa fa-calendar legend" id="date" style={styles.date_icon}></i><span class="legend" style={styles.date}>{tournament.dt}</span></div>
              <div><a href={tournament.tl} class="legend" style={styles.booknowmobile}>Book Now</a></div>
            </MediaQuery>
      </div>
      <div className={cssstyles.overlay}></div>
      <a href="#"> <img  src={tournament.img} /></a>
    </div>;
  }
```

But when I call the getSlide method from inside render() method, I gets this error Uncaught ReferenceError: getSlide is not defined

```
render() {
    var indicators=[];
    var images=[];
    this.state.tournaments.map(function(tournament,i){
      if(i==0){
        indicators.push(<li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="{i}" class="active"></li>);
        images.push(getSlide(tournament));
      }else
```

Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: 1- bind the map callback function or use arrow function like this: `this.state.tournaments.map((tournament,i) => {....}` 2- use `this.getSlide()` to call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSlide` function is not a global function, but a part of your component, so you need to call it with a context prefix, like `this.getSlide()`.

Also, since, you use `map` function, that creates own context, just calling `this.getSlide()` won't work, so you need to be aware that you call `getSlide` with a correct context. There are several options to do this:

For example:

```
//Option 1, with arrow function (if you use ES6)
render() {
    this.state.tournaments.map((tournament,i) => {
      this.getSlide(tournament)
    });
}

//Option 2, with saving context (if you use ES5)
render() {
    var self = this;
    this.state.tournaments.map(function(tournament,i){
      return self.getSlide(tournament)
    });
}

//Option 3, with binding context (if you use ES5)
render() {
    this.state.tournaments.map(function(tournament,i){
      return this.getSlide(tournament)
    }.bind(this));
}
```